# Select partial entities with specific columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In SqlAlchemy, I need to fetch partial entities with the given list of fields.

Other answers suggest to do any of the following:

```
session.query(User.id, User.login).all()
session.query(User).with_entities(User.id, User.login).all()
```

However, SA then returns column tuples:

```
[ (1, 'user1'), (2, 'user2') ]
```

How do I fetch objects of User instead of tuples and yet limit the retrieved columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [Deferred Column Loading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapper_config.html#deferred) section of the documentation. You might want to configure the default `deferred` behavior on the model itself, but in your case the following configuration should do it:

```
session.query(User).options(defer(User.name, User.nickname, ...)).all()
```

where you have to list all the columns you would like to defer loading from the database.

If you are lucky and have `sa.version>=0.9`, you can also use [`load_only`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapper_config.html#sqlalchemy.orm.load_only):

```
session.query(User).options(load_only(User.id, User.login)).all()
```

*Please note that you should load the `id` column (or other `primary_key` column(s)).*